# edittext doesn't perform filtering

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-edittext

I'm trying to filter the listview which is populating database. I was following tutorial, but somehow it doesn't perform as it was suppose to. I guess it's because of method in the class `fetchcountrybyname`. In the marked line it was saying that it can't use method which in non-static with something static, that why in instance was created, but still doesn't work.

Comment: are you using Russian country names?

Comment: @agamov  no I'm not using Russian country names